# Laravel Observer handle events twice

Tags: laravel, events, event-handling

In my laravel app I want to save histories of all actions (create,update,delete), to do this, I create `histories` table and I observe all `Models` and store in histories table on every event handled, 
**But,** when I handle the User `updated` event. for exemple, two row was saved on histories table, also when I handel the User `created` event. even with `ing` events.

**N.B :** I store user with `create()` method and I update it with `update()` method

UserObserver :

```
/**
     * Handle the User "created" event.
     */
    public function created(User $user): void
    {
        $user_resource =(new UserResource($user))->toResponse(request());
   
        $history = History::create([
            'model_type' => User::class,
            'model_id' => $user->id,
            'action' => 'create',
            'action_date' => now(),
            'model_object' => $user_resource->content(),
            'user_id' => request()->user()->id,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Handle the User "updated" event.
     */
    public function updated(User $user): void
    {
        $user_resource =(new UserResource($user))->toResponse(request());
        $history = History::create([
            'model_type' => User::class,
            'model_id' => $user->id,
            'action' => 'update',
            'action_date' => now(),
            'model_object' => $user_resource->content(),
            'user_id' => request()->user()->id,
        ]);
        // dd($history);

    }
```

**When I delete this lines**  :

```
/**
     * Handle the User "updated" event.
     */
```

no data was stored in histories table. I don't know the interst of this commented line and if thine lines handle the event twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that I define the `UserObserver` twice in `EventServiceProvider`